# Многопоточное выполнение скрипта на php

Tags: php

Встала проблема с многопоточностью в php.Необходимо разделять парсинг/генерацию чего-то между несколькими потоками.Приведите небольшой пример,если это возможно

> Говорят что в php нет многопоточности,тогда за пример "костыля" буду благодарен

*В гугле ничего толкового так и не нашёл.*

Comment: Если это делается из веб морды, то используйте связку js Ajax и JSON. Создав отдельные файлы для парсинга / генерации и запустив их отдельно.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V это едва ли не самое худшее, что можно посоветовать. Следующий вопрос будет про time_limit, после него будет вопрос про то, как работать с куки в cli-режиме.

Comment: @Etki, мое решение кажется мне самым простым в реализации. Можете объяснить мне почему оно плохое?

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V потому что скрипт умирает через тридцать секунд. Потому что запросы предназначены для выдачи ответа, а не обработки тяжелых данных. Потому что IPC то ли вообще нет, то ли он ведется через браузер. Потому что если клиент отключится, сервер волен сделать что угодно. Потому что это нельзя выполнять регулярно по расписанию. Потому что к этому надо прикручивать какуюто защиту от внешних запросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

зачем опять эти костыли? уже если уже есть [fork()](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148688/)

Comment: Объясните каплю. Я так понимаю с помощью данной функции идёт полная копия процесса. Но  не будет выглядеть она аналогично и например парсится одно и тоже?Или будет парсинг/генерация разделяться на разные урлы? (извиняюсь за тупость, запутался)

Comment: С сугугбо формальной точки зрения автор спрашивает про многопоточность, вы же говорит про новые процессы. Несмотря на то, что других опций и нет, стоило бы разъяснить, в чем разница и отметить, что это не многопоточность.

Comment: @Etki Да,косяк.Многопоточность по-своему была интересна. Думал тут можно и процесс ко всему прилепить, ну ладно. Пойду создавать новый вопрос :(

Comment: @Etki можете минусовать но о форках слишком много описано в сети. Да этот подход выделяет новые процессы что и реализует многопоточность. на сегодня это лучшее решение многопоточности в php

Comment: @username 1) я бы минусовал, если хотел 2) это НЕ многопоточность, многопоточность подразумевает существование параллельного выполнения в едином окружении.

Comment: @Etki согласен. Но в PHP есть один «нормальный» способ писать приложения, распределяющего процессы

Answer (score 0):

странно что никто не написал про curl_multi
с помощью curl_multi можно парсить одновременно несколько страниц.
правда curl_multi подходит только для парсинга.

Еще можно использовать воркеры